# Netlify Lambda Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, axios, netlify

I am having an issue getting a 502 error back when I call my Netlify function. Is there something I am doing wrong in my Axios call or does the "error" sent in the callback need to be an actual Error object?

Below is the example of my function:

```
const axios = require('axios')
require('dotenv').config()
const https = require('https')
const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
}

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  // your server-side functionality

  axios
    .post(
      `https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${
        process.env.LIST_ID
      }/members/`, {
        email_address: 'deuce3608@gmail.com',
        status: 'subscribed'
      }, {
        auth: {
          username: 'admin',
          password: process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
        }
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers,
        body: response.data
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      callback(JSON.stringify(err.response.data))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netlify [announced in April (2018)](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/04/03/node.js-8.10-now-available-in-netlify-functions/) that [Node.js 8.10](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) would be the default in Netlify functions.

## Using Callback Parameter:

When you need to return an error in `Lambda functions on Netlify` using the Callback Parameter, it will be the same format as the Lambda functions for AWS.

You will need to return an Error in the first parameter of the `callback` as you can see in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback)

```
callback(Error error, Object result);
```

The `error` is used if not null and the result will be ignored.

## Using Async Handler:

You also have the option to return your error in the response with an error status code like the example function below.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const API_ENDPOINT =
  "https://08ad1pao69.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/random_joke";

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  return fetch(API_ENDPOINT)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => ({
      statusCode: 200,
      body: `${data.setup} ${data.punchline} *BA DUM TSSS*`
    }))
    .catch(error => ({ statusCode: 422, body: String(error) }));
};
```

## Showing simple tests

#### Error

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const err = new Error("this is an error")
  callback(err);
}
```

**Response (response status code 502):**

```
{"errorMessage":"this is an error","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["48.exports.handler (/var/task/showerror.js:75:13)"]}
```

#### Object

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const err = {statusCode: 422, body: "this is an error"}
  callback(err);
}
```

**Response (response status code 502):**

```
{"errorMessage":"[object Object]"}
```

#### String

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const err = "this is an error"
  callback(err);
}
```

**Response (response status code 502):**

```
{"errorMessage":"this is an error"}
```

### NOTE:

If you want to use callback and have the error status code in the response, you would just pass it in an object to the response.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const err = {statusCode: 422, body: "this is an error"}
  callback(null, err);
}
```

**Response (response status code 422):**

```
this is an error
```

Comment: So it can’t just be any ol object returned? It HAS to be an Error object? If I’m understanding correctly?

Comment: I have not tested any object, but from the docs it just passes the error (first parameter) to be populated to the response when using the callback function.

Comment: I did the tests in a Netlify Function for `callback` using `Error`,`Object`, and `String` and added it to the answer. I also included the passing of the result instead, so you can see how it returns the status code given.

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange the response like so:

```
var response = {
    statusCode: 4xx
    body: ''
}
```

and then pass it to the callback to return the error

```
response.body = 'some error text here';
callback(response);
```

They are using AWS Lambda, so if you can do it in the console you should in theory be able to call things the same way since they are taking your code and deploying it via Cloudformation in their infrastructure.